# I've installed powershell in ubuntu 16.04 but when I type powershell in terminal it says command not found, how can I fix this?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I've installed `powershell` from a `powershell_6.0.0-alpha.9-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb` package I've downloaded form GitHub and typed following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind8 libicu55
sudo dpkg -i powershell_6.0.0-beta.9-1.ubuntu.16.04_amd64.deb
```

But when I run `powershell` on terminal it says dependencies aren't installed. So I removed `powershell` with

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

(to clean unmet dependencies) and

```
sudo apt purge powershell
```

Then I started installation again with following commands

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y powershell
```

But after the installation is finished and I wanted to run the `powershell` by typing it on terminal but it says `command not found`

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: run `sudo dpkg-query -l powershell` and lets see the output!

Comment: Unrelated to the main issue (for which you have answers already): FYI, "autoremove" does NOT *clean unmet dependencies*. It cleans no longer needed, orphaned, packages. Those packages are only wasting space and typically so little that can be ignored, they don't in any way interact or prevent installing and using other software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right command for starting powershell is `pwsh` not `powershell`

For complete installation please refer [Install Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1#ubuntu-1604)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I see from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1#ubuntu-1604) use the command:

```
pwsh
```